# how to force weblogic to load classes from web-inf/lib

Tags: classloader, weblogic12c

This question originates from the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55886819/classcastexception-org-slf4j-impl-jdk14loggerfactory-cannot-be-cast-to-ch-qos)

Essentially I would like the slf4j jar to be loaded from my war's web-inf\lib and NOT from weblogic's legacy jars.

NOTE - am deploying a WAR and NOT an EAR file.
In **weblogic.xml** tried the following :

```
<wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-application-resources>
        <wls:resource-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:resource-name>
        <wls:resource-name>ch.qos.*</wls:resource-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-resources>
</wls:container-descriptor>
```

However weblogic is still loading these classes from its legacy jars and not from my application's web-inf\lib

Could someone suggest any other approach ?

Answer (score 1):

those tags are only for the resources, you need the Filtering Classloader :

```
<wls:prefer-application-packages>
    <wls:package-name>org.slf4j</wls:package-name>
    <wls:package-name>ch.qos</wls:package-name>
</wls:prefer-application-packages>
```

Another approach is to use: `prefer-web-inf-classes`
(you cannot use both)

More info: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/classloading.htm#WLPRG315